# track a redirect page with google analytics

Tags: php, redirect, google-analytics

I am trying to track a redirect page with google analytics:
I have a page called `redirect.php`; when I visit an url like `redirect.php?c=12345678` , a php function does a query on a sql lookup table to decode the code `12345678` with a previously inserted url, then does a `301` redirect.

(I'm doing a `301` redirect to avoid duplicate content.)
I wish to track every single visit to `redirect.php` with analytics, but I can't.

For example:

`redirect.php?c=87654321` redirects to `story.php`.

Obviously in Analytics I can't find the `redirect.php` page. the `story.php` referer is `organic/google` so I can't rely on the referer.

Is it possible to track every redirect in some ways?

Comment: Looks like the analytics API is smart enough to bypass routing pages like your redirect.php, interesting... Can you try to include a 'home-made' tracking script like analytics to make sure that it's working?

Comment: @Gianluca Fabrizi - Did you ever come up with a solution for this? If so can you share it?

Comment: @meder - no, not with analytics.
You can do it with piwik and it's php api:
http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GA works in the browser. Whenever the user visits a page with the GA script - a request from the user to google is sent notifying about the visit. 
Since you are making a 301 header redirect - no GA script is loaded and therefore google doesn't know the user has been on that page.

Options you have

- Switch the redirect from 301 header to a page with meta redirect and the GA code
- Switch to another analytics system such as Piwik and add data to it manually on the redirect page
- Implement your own counter inside the redirect script, separated from GA

Of course you could merge the options and have, say a page with meta redirect and the GA code, which redirects to redirect.php script, which in turn redirects with a 301 header, but this is not the best solution.

Comment: I have tried adding a meta redirect to redirect.php:
`<META  HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=<?php echo $link; ?>">`
GA still doesn't see this page (neither as a referer). I have added a code of another analytics system (javascript code) near the GA code; the new code sees the page redirect.php as a destination page and as a referer too.
The problem seems to be with Google...

Comment: That probably happens due to the 0 seconds timeout, while the GA scripts takes more time to load, initialize, take and analyze the data and only then send it to Google. Try increasing the timeout.

Comment: The counter idea is the cleanest option I've heard so far on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Analytics code BEFORE the redirect.

Comment: already done; the analytics code is on top of redirect.php page.

Comment: This usually won't work because the headers are already sent: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`